# How to make a definition and evalulation for a sequence

Tags: list-manipulation, series-expansion

Here a example of sequenze (unfortanely i could not copy/paste  as Latex ?)

[image: sequenze]

How to input this in MMA ?

**EDIT**: example 2 : for n = 8

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Try adding what you have tried. Have you seen [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html)?

Comment: A list , yes, but a subscript with Ctrl + _ ?

Comment: Using subscripts `Array[Subscript[a, #]&, 15]`; however, I recommend using indexed variables instead, i.e.,  `Format[a[n_]] := Subscript[a, n]; Array[a, 15]`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon , now getting the whole expression..?

Comment: I do not understand your comment

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, There is a equation for input and you are giving the RHS, so what will be the LHS ?
Does MMA has a sequenze command ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to efficiently typeset such a formula (only as a reading material, not as code for subsequent programming) in _Mathematica_?

Comment: @xzcd , the LHS as reading material and the RHS as code for subsequent programming) in Mathematica

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Format[a[n_]] := Subscript[a, n];

Format[aseq[n_]] := Subscript[{a["n"]}, "n=1.." <> ToString[n]]

n = 15;

aseq[n] == Array[a, n]
```

[image]

Clear["Global`*"]

**EDIT:** For the revised question,

```
Subscript[{1/"n"}, "n=1..∞"] == 
 Append[seq = Array[1/# &, 8], …]
```

[image]

For subsequent calculations use `seq`

```
seq

(* {1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, 1/6, 1/7, 1/8} *)
```

Comment: Compared with Maple it looks complicated in MMA?, Maple code example:
`{a[n]}[n=1..15]=seq(a[n],n=1..15);`

Comment: Perhaps a simpler formulation possible in MMA

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. If you just want to generate a sequence, the only thing necessary is `Array[a, 15]`. All the rest is just formatting for display.

Comment: See question EDIT for example 2 . LHS is notation and RHS is the actual sequenze

Comment: Bob Hanlon, yes, that are the right commands, rather easy to use in other sequenzes i think.

Comment: Is this expression a equation ? : 

`Subscript[{1/"n"}, "n=1..∞"] == 
 Append[seq = Array[1/# &, 8], …]`

Comment: Only in a general sense. It cannot be used readily in subsequent calculations. That is why the definition of `seq` was embedded so that the sequence would be defined/remembered for reuse.

Comment: How the MMA code is constructed for these row examples, you can't really call that intuitive anymore. A student with MMA will certainly not come up with this way of doing his assignments.
I copied the two row examples in Maple and that looks much easier what the teacher ( professor) worked out

Of course, I could have also given the 2 maple code sequencing examples and started to recreate them in MMA.
Wouldn't that be easier ?
-------------------------------------------
example 3 
`Subscript[{Sqrt[3*"n" - 7]}, "n=3..8"] == Append[seq = Array[Sqrt[3*#1 - 7] & , 5, 3], 
   \[Ellipsis]]`

Comment: I think that the answer of the tasks for a student in this book are made by a Maple specialist 
The student must do it manually with pen and paper their college math.

Comment: If you have additional questions, don't ask them in comments. Post a new question. Note your LHS only runs from 3 to 8 so the ellipsis is not appropriate.

Comment: The idea was mine to follow your code logic from the second row example 2 and apply it in a third example which I put in the comments.
Apparently, there is an error in it anyway.

Comment: Its a raw inputform conversion here in comment translated ?

Answer (score 3):

```
Table[Subscript[a, i] = 1/i, {i, 1, 8}]
```

To check manually:

```
{Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 2], Subscript[a, 3], Subscript[a, 4], \
Subscript[a, 5], Subscript[a, 6], Subscript[a, 7], Subscript[a, 8]}
```

Or

```
Subscript[a, #] & /@ Range[8]
```

> {1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, 1/6, 1/7, 1/8}

Comment: Thanks . LHS is only notation for example 2 , so a equal sign makes it complicated? 
My attempt : `HoldForm[Subscript[{1/n}, n = ((1)..)*Infinity]] == Table[1/n, {n, 8}]`

It is not complete : , ...   added to the end :)

Comment: I think the formatting has been addressed by Bob Hanlon's answer. Use indexed variables. Subscripts don't play nice. There is a clear difference between computation and presentation built-in to the architecture of Mma. Mma likes to keep it in a computable state so that an output can be used as input for subsequent operations.

Comment: I need to be able to write down the row definition smoothly without having to think too much about how to code it.
The actual calculation in MMA happens on the right side of the definition and can be used for further calculation if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Still, your question is unclear. You should put more effort in clarifying your question. Anyway, do you want this?:

```
<< Notation`

Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
   SubscriptBox[RowBox[{"{", "e_", "}"}], 
    RowBox[{"n_", " ", "=", " ", 
      RowBox[{"a_", " ", "to", " ", "b_"}]}]]] ⟺ 
     ParsedBoxWrapper[
   RowBox[{"table", "[", 
     RowBox[{"e_", ",", RowBox[{"{", RowBox[{"n_",",", "a_", ",", "b_"}], "}"}]}],
     "]"}]]]

table[e_, {n_, a_, Infinity}] := Append[Table[e, {n, a, a + 7}], …]
table[a__] := Table[a]

h2 = Function[a, (HoldForm[a = #1] &)[a], HoldAll];

table[Subscript[a, n], {n, 1, 15}] // h2

table[1/i, {i, 1, ∞}] // h2
```

[image]

Comment: @xczd,thanks. easy sequenze definition  here with `Print [ ]` 

`Print["{\!\(\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(n\)]\)\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(}\), \
\(n = \(1 .. \) \
\[Infinity]\)]\) = ", Table[1/n, {n, 8}]]`

Only adding ,... after the last number 1/8 ,... seems to be troublesome

Comment: @xczd , making function h2 general for every sequenze ? : adding to the last number  a in the row :  ,...   ( comma with 3 dots )

Comment: @janhardo Please read the document of `Append` carefully. Once again, I'd like to emphasize that, get used to reading the document of *Mathematica* by pressing **F1** is the first thing to learn for a beginner.

Comment: @xcczd, thank.  In this form in MMA : example `Print[
  "(\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(3  n - 7\)]\)\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\()\), \(n = \(3 .. \) 8\)]\) = ", 
  Table[Sqrt[3*n - 7], {n, 3, 10}]]`